# Removing EventListener

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have an application which will create a textarea wherever the user clicks. However, I want the pane to only be editable when a certain condition is true. The clickable area never goes away, though. How can I change this so the area is only clickable if **myAnchorPane.isVisible()** is true?

```
double oldHeight = 0;
double oldWidth = 0;
@FXML
private void handleTextButton() {
    System.out.println("Text Clicked");
    TextHeaderTools.setVisible(false);
    BackgroundTools.setVisible(false);
    VideoTools.setVisible(false);
    PageTitleTools.setVisible(false);
    TemplateTools.setVisible(false);
    ImageTools.setVisible(false);
    TextTools.setVisible(true);


    workspace.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            int x = (int) me.getX();
            int y = (int) me.getY();

            System.out.println("(" + x +", " + y +")");

            InlineCssTextArea newArea = new InlineCssTextArea();
            newArea.relocate(x, y);
            newArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
            Text textHolder = new Text();
            newArea.setPrefSize(40,40);

            textHolder.textProperty().bind(newArea.textProperty());
            textHolder.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
                    if (oldHeight != newValue.getHeight()) {
                        oldHeight = newValue.getHeight();
                        newArea.setPrefHeight(textHolder.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() + 30);
                    }
                    if (oldWidth != newValue.getWidth()){
                        oldWidth = newValue.getWidth();
                        newArea.setPrefWidth(textHolder.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() + 30); 
                    }
                }
            });             

            workspace.getChildren().addAll(newArea);


        } //end handle

    });

}
```

EDIT:

The condition is

```
myAnchorPane.isVisible()
```

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between anything in your question and the question title. Which event listener are you wanting to remove? Also, if I understand the question correctly, you just want to make the text area editable under certain conditions. It's hard to answer the question without a little more information about what that condition is.

Comment: Just wrap the code inside your handler in the conditional statement; that way it'll only execute when the condition is true. If you want to literally remove the handler when the boolean is true, either create a setter method which calls `removeEventHandler` when the value is set to false

Comment: @VinceEmigh Such a simple solution, I think I will try this. I tried something similar, but I wrapped the ENTIRE handler in the if statement and it still always ran. I will try this,thank you!

Comment: Let me know if it works. If not, I'll create a chat for this question so we can discuss structure. The boolean may need to be atomic, depending on which thread changes the boolean and which thread accesses it to read it's value. I also highly suggest checking out the answer from @TomasMikula; he shows you an easier way to manage what you want using RichTextFX, a library you are already using

Comment: @VinceEmigh the condition is actually myAnchorPane.isVisible(), I hope it still works in this case.

Comment: You should edit that info into your question, just in case. You could still synchronize if needed, or use [`AtomicBoolean#set(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#set(boolean)) to set the value of the atomic boolean using `isVisible()` as the value. This is only needed if the thread reading the variable isnt the same thread as the one changing it. Check which threads you're working on

Comment: @VinceEmigh Updates to `visibleProperty()` as well as event dispatching (click handling) are both happening on the JavaFX application thread, so I don't see the need for synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this nicely with [ReactFX](http://www.reactfx.org/).

Instead of `workspace.addEventHandler(MOUSE_CLICKED, ...)`, do this:

```
EventStreams.eventsOf(workspace, MOUSE_CLICKED)
        .suppressWhen(myAnchorPane.visibleProperty().not())
        .subscribe((MouseEvent me) -> {
            // handle mouse click
        });
```

I see you use RichTextFX, so you already have ReactFX as a dependency anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out! I wasn't aware of ReactFX.

Comment: @user2130057 Taking into account that your condition is `myAnchorPane.isVisible()`,   define `disabled` in the above code as `myAnchorPane.visibleProperty().not()`.

Comment: I incorporated this into the answer.